# Getting Errors in creating a Neo4j cluster with two instance

Tags: neo4j

I am trying to create a cluster of neo4j with two instance with the configurations given in

http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/ha-setup-tutorial.html

I tried many things but not able to run when i add the another IP in initial_hosts entry and restart the server it will not start.

when i run the command neo4j.bat

```
 INFO  Write transactions to database disabled  
 INFO  Initiating metrics..
 INFO  Attempting to join cluster of [IP of my pc:5001, ip of another pc:5001]
```

and server started but when i hit the localhost:7474 it is not working.

my other configurations are in my pc:

neo4j.properties

```
ha.cluster_server=my IP on my machine:5001
ha.server=IP of my pc:6363
ha.server_id=1
online_backup_server=ip of my pc:6366
```

neo4j-server.properties

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

i have enabled the log properties also

```
org.neo4j.server.http.log.config=conf/neo4j-http-logging.xml
```

but no log file is created.

Comment: go through the https://github.com/MicTech/neo4j-ha-configuration link also but nothing works..

Answer (score 0):

For each node you need to use different port.

**neo4j01/conf/neo4j.properties**

```
ha.cluster_server=localhost:5001
ha.server=localhost:6363
ha.server_id=1
online_backup_server=localhost:6366
ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001,localhost:5002
```

**neo4j01/conf/neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

**neo4j02/conf/neo4j.properties**

```
ha.cluster_server=localhost:5002
ha.server=localhost:6363
ha.server_id=2
online_backup_server=localhost:6366
ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001,localhost:5002
```

**neo4j02/conf/neo4j-server.properties**

```
org.neo4j.server.database.mode=HA
org.neo4j.server.webserver.address=0.0.0.0
```

Here is the example how to run cluster on your local machine - https://github.com/MicTech/neo4j-ha-configuration

Comment: @MicText I have done the same configurations as you have provided.but still when i do neo4j.bat server start with                       `INFO  Write transactions to database disabled
 INFO  Initiating metrics..
 INFO  Attempting to join cluster of [localhost:5001, localhost:5002]` and when i hit the localhost:7474 it will not work is there any other configuration needed to create a cluster

Comment: for the first instance i have given the **ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001** and for the second i have given the **ha.initial_hosts=localhost:5001,localhost:5002** then only i am able to start the server successfully but the same thing i am applying with two diffrenent machines that is not working for me

Comment: @akshayjain: could you please show us information from logs?